# How can I randomly select one element from a vector or array?

Tags: rust

I have a vector where the element is a `(String, String)`. How can I randomly pick one of these elements?

Answer (score 113, accepted):

You want the [`rand`](https://crates.io/crates/rand/) crate, specifically the [`choose`](https://docs.rs/rand/0.7.2/rand/seq/trait.SliceRandom.html#tymethod.choose) method.

```
use rand::seq::SliceRandom; // 0.7.2

fn main() {
    let vs = vec![0, 1, 2, 3, 4];
    println!("{:?}", vs.choose(&mut rand::thread_rng()));
}
```

Comment: I'd disagree. The only differences with this approach and other languages are the need to put the trait in scope and manually needing to specify where the rng state comes from.

Perhaps a tad more explicit than usual, but I find it okay.

Answer (score 22):

Using [`choose_multiple`](https://docs.rs/rand/0.7.2/rand/seq/trait.SliceRandom.html#tymethod.choose_multiple):

```
use rand::seq::SliceRandom; // 0.7.2

fn main() {
    let samples = vec!["hi", "this", "is", "a", "test!"];
    let sample: Vec<_> = samples
        .choose_multiple(&mut rand::thread_rng(), 1)
        .collect();
    println!("{:?}", sample);
}
```

Answer (score 13):

Another choice for weighted sampling that is already included in the `rand` crate is [`WeightedIndex`](https://docs.rs/rand/0.7.2/rand/distributions/weighted/struct.WeightedIndex.html), which has an example:

> ```
> use rand::prelude::*;
> use rand::distributions::WeightedIndex;
>
> let choices = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
> let weights = [2,   1,   1];
> let dist = WeightedIndex::new(&weights).unwrap();
> let mut rng = thread_rng();
> for _ in 0..100 {
>     // 50% chance to print 'a', 25% chance to print 'b', 25% chance to print 'c'
>     println!("{}", choices[dist.sample(&mut rng)]);
> }
>
> let items = [('a', 0), ('b', 3), ('c', 7)];
> let dist2 = WeightedIndex::new(items.iter().map(|item| item.1)).unwrap();
> for _ in 0..100 {
>     // 0% chance to print 'a', 30% chance to print 'b', 70% chance to print 'c'
>     println!("{}", items[dist2.sample(&mut rng)].0);
> }
> ```

Answer (score 7):

If you want to choose more than one element then the [random_choice](https://crates.io/crates/random_choice) crate may be right for you:

```
extern crate random_choice;
use self::random_choice::random_choice;

fn main() {
    let mut samples = vec!["hi", "this", "is", "a", "test!"];
    let weights: Vec<f64> = vec![5.6, 7.8, 9.7, 1.1, 2.0];

    let number_choices = 100;
    let choices = random_choice().random_choice_f64(&samples, &weights, number_choices);

    for choice in choices {
        print!("{}, ", choice);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

If you also want to **remove** the chosen element, here's one way to do that (using the `rand` crate):

```
let mut vec = vec![0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];

let index = (rand::random::<f32>() * vec.len() as f32).floor() as usize;
let value = vec.remove( index );

println!("index: {} value: {}", index, value);
println!("{:?}", vec);
```

[Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=10fc430ad87f7fa0e1ff8a6eecbcf4f4)

`remove(index)` removes that value at `index` (shifting all the elements after it to the left) and the returns the value that was at `index` ([docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.remove)).

Answer (score 2):

Another way of getting a random value is via the indexing method using [rng.gen_range](https://docs.rs/rand/latest/rand/trait.Rng.html#method.gen_range) and [vec.get()](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.get). This also prevents the borrowing of the value (which occurs with the [vec.choose()](https://docs.rs/rand/0.7.2/rand/seq/trait.SliceRandom.html#tymethod.choose) method)

```
fn main() {
    let mut rng = rand::thread_rng();

    let my_strings : Vec<&str> = vec!["a", "b", "c"];
    let random_string_index: usize = rng.gen_range(0..my_strings.len());
    let string = my_strings[random_string_index];
    println!("{:?}", string);
}
```